# Import in node js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I import this code in module.exports ?

I'm pretty new in node js and in js.
I want that this code could be used in other routes

```
 cache = (duration) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    let key = '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url
    let cachedBody = mcache.get(key)
    if (cachedBody) {
      res.send(cachedBody)
      return
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send
      res.send = (body) => {
        mcache.put(key, body, duration * 1000);
        res.sendResponse(body)
      }
      next()
    }
  }
}
```

How can I export it?

I was something like :

```
module.exports =    cache = (duration) => {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        let key = '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url
        let cachedBody = mcache.get(key)
        if (cachedBody) {
          res.send(cachedBody)
          return
        } else {
          res.sendResponse = res.send
          res.send = (body) => {
            mcache.put(key, body, duration * 1000);
            res.sendResponse(body)
          }
          next()
        }
      }
    }
```

Also I try:

```
module.export = {
  cache:   function(duration)  {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    let key = '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url
    let cachedBody = mcache.get(key)
    if (cachedBody) {
      res.send(cachedBody)
      return
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send
      res.send = (body) => {
        mcache.put(key, body, duration * 1000);
        res.sendResponse(body)
      }
      next()
    }
  }
}
}
```

But when I try to use it in a get request:

```
var expCache = require('../../middleware/cache');
    router.get('/:sid/fe',expCache.cache(3000),function(req,res) {
```

It brings:

```
TypeError: expCache.cache is not a function
```

Regards

Comment: *for loop with git*? Sorry, where is the git here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export an object, if you're expecting to be able to call `expCache.cache`:

```
module.exports = {
  cache: // your function
}
```

However, if you want to keep your exported module as it is, just call it like this instead:

```
// inside middleware/cache:
// module.exports = cache = (duration) => {

var expCache = require('../../middleware/cache');

// you can call it as just a function
router.get('/:sid/fe', expCache(3000), function(req,res) {
```

Comment: I understand this. But it marks something in the = character: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var expCache = require('../../middleware/cache');
router.get('/:sid/fe',expCache(3000),function(req,res) {..
```

You're exporting your cache function already, not an object containing it (which is how you try to use it for your router).

Comment: I tried that, but doesnt work... it doesn't gets through dthe file